# Utilizar Truques matemáticos, pode acelerar contas em Python?

Tags: python, desempenho, matemática

Um exemplo de código sobre minha duvida.

```
%timeit lambda : 10000000000000000*10000000000000000
40.4 ns ± 0.592 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)


%timeit lambda : "10000000000000000"+"10000000000000000"[1:]
40.6 ns ± 0.0841 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

Comment: Qual é o truque matemático? Aliás, o que entende por "truque"? Na primeira você multiplica dois inteiros, na segunda você soma duas strings; não entendi a relação entre os exemplos.

Comment: Não, na segunda o resultado também é a multiplicação!

Comment: O truque, neste caso, seria o fato de somar os ZEROS, para obter o mesmo resultado.

Comment: Mas são operações bem distintas. Em uma você efetua a multiplicação de inteiros (e obtém um inteiro como resultado), na outra você concatena duas *strings* (e obtém uma *string* como resultado). Ainda não consegui entender que tipo de comparação deseja fazer.

Comment: é apenas uma duvida, se computacionalmente, poderia existir alguma vantagem em tempo de execução, em algum cenário especifico. Eu não conheço muito sobre o processamento em mais baixo nível, por isso a pergunta.

Comment: e sobre a string, é so passar ela para int

Comment: Pra mim não faz sentido o que está tentando fazer. Se quer multiplicar 2 números, use os valores numéricos. O fato de concatenar strings e trazer o "mesmo" resultado é irrelevante. Até porque vc está confundindo as coisas. Um número é um valor... numérico. Por exemplo, `2` é um número, mas pode ser representado de várias maneiras: como a string `"2"`, ou  "dois", ou "two", etc. O fato de uma string ter o caractere `'2'` não quer dizer que ela é o mesmo que o número 2 (já que os tipos são diferentes - um é `int`, outro é `str`). Ao imprimir, o resultado é o "mesmo", mas é "coincidência"

Comment: E o seu `timeit` só está criando o *lambda*, mas não está executando, então vc está verificando os tempos de criação dos *lambdas*. De qualquer forma, um está multiplicando números e o outro está concatenando strings, não há nada de "truques matemáticos" nisso.

Comment: intendi! obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que você está tentando fazer não faz sentido em Python.

À parte de você estar usando uma operação muito específica, que usa codepaths completamente diferentes, devolve objetos diferentes, e não poderia ser utilizada para outros números - Python é uma linguagem de "muito alto nível" - em termos gerais, isso significa que ela é separada do que acontece no hardware por muitas camadas, de forma a propíciar simplicidade para escrever o código.

Perceba que em nenhum dos seus exemplos você tem que se preocupar em reservar memória para as strings, verificar se o tamanho do número é compatível com a arquitetura da CPU  - e não teria que se preocupar com outras dezenas de detalhes se a computação que você precisa fosse mais complexa.

Isso por que o Python *abstrai* os tipos de dados pra você: você lida com "inteiros do Python" que são objetos, e não tipos de dados nativos da CPU. O mesmo vale para as strings - você nem tem que saber qual tipo de dado é usado para armazenar cada caractere de uma string de Python em memória.

Tudo isso acoplado num runtime bem otimizado ao longo de décadas faz com que para muitas "do mundo real" operações praticamente não faça diferença usar Python ou uma linguagem de mais baixo nível: interpolar um template HTML com dados que foram  lidos de um banco SQL? Todas as operações custozas são escritas em código nativo, o seu código em Python simplesmente organiza as informações.

Mas se você fizer questão de não saber como um computador e como  a linguagem funciona, pode querer, por exemplo, escrever código que faça contas com inteiros em Python puro - e nesse caso acabar com uma rotina que seja cerca de 10000 vezes mais lenta que código nativo.

Então, otimizações do tipo que você está propondo (apesar do exemplo ruim), não tem qualquer sentido em Python: a multiplicação (de números que caibam num registrador da CPU), já vai ser milhares de vezes mais lenta do que se feita em C, ou mesmo em Java, que apesar de interpretar bytecode como o Python, usa tipos numéricos nativos sem tradução.

Em Python o que se faz é, depois que se descobre o algoritmo, usar as partes que exigem cálculo numérico intensivo em bibliotecas nativas - por isso o Python é a linguagem mais usada para criar aplicações em aprendizagem de máquina por exemplo: toda a maquinaria numérica é disponibilizada para uso a partir do Python em bibliotecas como o Tensorflow. A mesma coisa se você precisa de cálculo numérico mais direto: vai usar o Numpy, que tem código nativo para aplicar a operação em milhares ou milhões de números de uma vez de forma bastante otimizada.

Mas um simples algoritmo de fatoração de números em Python puro vai ser milhares de vezes mais lento que em outras linguagens. O caminho pra se otimizar se você tem um algoritmo certo em Python, mas que não está implementado numa biblioteca pronta, é usar o Cython, que pode otimizar código Python como código nativo, por exemplo.

Comment: Perfeito, eram estes motivos que eu queria saber, muito obrigado. agora eu tenho uma direção.